# Laravel Nova 3 - Resource Fields Error - BelongsTo - "Trying to get property 'resourceClass' of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I am new to Laravel's Nova and finding it good so far, however, in some of my Resource Fields I use the "BelongsTo::make" to reference a relationship that has been defined in the Model.

It works well on the Index page which shows the vehicle that it is referenced to and on the Update and Create pages I am expecting to see a Select input generated with so that the user can choose which vehicle they want, however, I am getting the following error:

> Trying to get property 'resourceClass' of non-object

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `vehicle_service` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `vehicle_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE `vehicles` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
)
```

**Laravel Model**

```
class VehicleService extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'vehicle_service';

    protected $casts = [
        'last_service_date' => 'date',
    ];

    public function vehicle() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vehicle::class, 'vehicle_id');
    }

}
```

**Laravel Nova Resource**

```
class VehicleService extends Resource
{

    public static $model = \App\Models\VehicleService::class;

    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
        ];
    }

    public function fieldsForIndex(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            BelongsTo::make('Vehicle', 'vehicle', 'App\Nova\Vehicle')
            ->rules('required')
            ->viewable(false),
        ];
    }

    public function fieldsForDetail(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        BelongsTo::make('Vehicle', 'vehicle', 'App\Nova\Vehicle')
        ->viewable(false),
    }
}
```

**API Path**
I came across this suggestion on [GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/76#issuecomment-416001820) but removing the dash between vehicle-services seems to have no impact
    `/nova-api/vehicle-services/associatable/vehicle?first=false&search=&withTrashed=false&resourceId=2&viaResource=&viaResourceId=&viaRelationship=`

Versions:

- PHP - v7.4.5
- Laravel - v7.15.0
- Nova - v3.6.0

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Laravel Nova 3.0, you can check the issue tracker information here:

https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/2770